# Website Mobile Navigation bar is visible to the right of the toggle button HTML CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: Issue]

The website works fine in desktop view but the media query navigation bar on mobile is shown in the rightmost corner so it's not really hidden

**CSS**

```
links{
    position:absolute;
    background:#f44336;
    padding:5px;
    line-height: 50px;
    height:100vh;
    width:200px;
    top:0;
    right:-200px;
    text-align: left; 
    z-index:2;
    transition: 1s;
    }
```

**js**

```
<SCRIPT>
var navLinks = document.getElementById("navLinks");
function showMenu(){
    navLinks.style.right = "0px";
}
function hideMenu(){
    navLinks.style.right = "-200px";

}
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9VoD.jpg

Comment: Your question doesn't contain any question. What exactly is your problem? Can you provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

Set right = "-999px" maybe can work on mobile like what you want:

```
<script>
var navLinks = document.getElementById("navLinks");
function showMenu(){
    navLinks.style.right = "0px";
}
function hideMenu(){
    navLinks.style.right = "-999px";

}
</script>
```